# How can I redirect the user to a web page when an image is clicked in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Link(
            target: LinkTarget.blank,
            uri: Uri.parse('https://en.mentornity.com/corporate-mentoring-software'),
            builder: (context, followLink) => DetailsCard(
              onTap: followLink,
              color: violet,
              title: 'Şirket İçi\nMentorluk',
              networkImage:
                  'https://en.mentornity.com/assets/img/64f829097a59b73fd8b31dc3f5509a3f.jpg',
            ),
          ),
```

My card widget where I combine properties such as visuals, titles, and the website that the user will go to when they click.

```
Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Image.network(
          networkImage,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          opacity: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.35),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          style: detailsCard,
        ),
      ))
    ]),
```

This is the card widget I created. I defined an onTap function and wrapped the image with GestureDetector and added my own `final Function()? onTap;` I synced my definition. I then called this where I wanted to use it and added the link where I wanted to redirect the user. But it gives me **Could not launch link** error.

The flutter package I use: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 `  <application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I also got the internet permission.

Comment: could you include the part you call luncher? could you include followLink function?

Answer (score 0):

For me, everything worked perfectly fine with:

```
launchUrl(
    Uri.parse(
        "https://en.mentornity.com/corporate-mentoring-software",
    ),
);
```

But did you make sure that your app has all the necessary permissions and the Uri is correctly formatted?